# Hadoop join with String key

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm implementing a reduce-side join to find matches between databases A and B. Both files from the datasets contains a json object per line. The join key is the name attribute of each record, so, the mapper extract the name of the json and pass it as key and the json itself as value. The reducer must merge the jsons objects for the same or similar person name.

The problem is that I need to group keys using a string similarity matching algorithm, e.g., John White must be considered equal to John White Lennon.

I've tried to do that using a grouping comparator but it is not working as expected.

How can this be implemented?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you request here could be described as a set similarity join, where the sets are, e.g. the sets of tokens, or n-grams of each line. Here is a [research paper](http://flamingo.ics.uci.edu/pub/sigmod10-vernica.pdf), that describes how you can achieve that in MapReduce. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood some concepts of MapReduce. Isn't there a way to override how Hadoop groups the keys? For example, when implementing secondary sort, you can set the grouping to be done only by the natural key, which is basically a compareTo method, so, I thought that this grouping could be done with a string similarity matching algorithm.

Comment: The paper appears to be very useful, thank you, I will read it later! But I'm a bit confused and curious to know what have I done wrong or what concept I let pass through. I'm only using one reducer, so I guess custom partitioners will not have any effect.

Comment: That's true. I saw your other question and removed my previous comment.

Comment: The paper was very useful, so I accepted your answer as it seems to be the best way to implement this. However, it is related to sets of normalized data and do not appear to deal with similarity of tokens, which is one critical requirement for my job. Just for a closure, can you confirm my last statement?

Comment: On the contrary, it is a very general definition that can cover the similarity of documents, if they are represented as sets of tokens. (I am not one of the authors by the way - just to make it clear :)